# can't create multiple aps with raspberry pi pico w (multiple ssids, one device)

Tags: networking, wifi, access-point

Right this is driving me mad as I cant find any information on it online and AI has been no help at all.

To put it simply, I need to make multiple networks with different ssids from a raspberry pi pico w in micro python. I can create one just fine however I need to make around 10 for this demonstration I'm doing in some presentation.

this is the code I have so far:

```
import network

def create_ap(ssid):
    
    password = "Testing123"
    
    ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
    ap.config(essid=ssid, password=password)

    ap.active(True)

    while ap.active == False:
      pass

    print("Access point active")
    print(ap.ifconfig())
    

create_ap("WIFIONE")
create_ap("WIFITWO")
```

Which seems like it should work, especially as excluding the last line works perfectly, however this only created the first WIFIONE access point.

From the small amount of information I've gathered there's a chance this just wont work with the raspberry pi Pico w as of hardware limitations, which if that is the case I'll just have to ignore it and make do with one AP.

Also this is my first time using stack exchange so I apologise if my etiquette on here isn't quite right as this really is a last resort from my lack of hardware knowledge. Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess my first thought would be that it cant run multiple at the same time. Do you have anything that says it can?  If you add additional print statements, you would at least be able to confirm its getting setup (is it getting stuck in the loop waiting to become active?) are you getting errors or just dont see the second network show up on other devices?

Comment: ah thank you for trying to help! My first thought was also that it just couldn't run two at the same time, I haven't found anything which says it can or anything which says it cant so I just assumed it could (I wouldn't even know what I'm looking for tbh). the print statements currently there say both are active but on any other devices its just not showing up. On a second look it does appear that the ifconfig for both access points are exactly the same which could be a slight issue, this still doesn't explain why only the first ssid is used though, thanks again for your help and time so far